# WiFi connectivity on iPod touch

Tags: ipod-touch, wifi

I have an iPod touch and its WiFi seems to have this "awkward" feature.

Lets say that A and B are two WiFi networks to which I have the passwords or are free.
When I move out of the range of A into the range of B, I seem to have to manually reconnect my WiFi to B.

Is there a way out of this continuous manual intervention?

I thought that WiFi connectivity is a one-time thing. Once I have logged into one network then I will again be automatically logged into it the next time I get into its range. But that doesn't seem to be happening on my iPod touch.

Can anyone tell me if there is a way around this issue?

Comment: So, which network do you want to connect to?  A or B?

Comment: @Anirbit Does the same occur when you go from B to A? Also, how far apart are the networks (i.e., could the touch still think it's connected to A when it should switch to B)?

Answer (score -1):

## "Forget" WiFi networks you don't want to automatically join.

Your iPod touch will automatically join any network that it has previously joined.  In order to prevent it from jumping on any of these network automatically, you must "forget" them.  Go to the wifi settings, tap the little blue arrow to the right of the network you want to prevent your device from joining, and then at the top, tap, "forget network". (exact wording?)

Hope this helps.